# Redirect argument from a file to a Linux command

Tags: linux, shell

I searched the Internet, but maybe I used the wrong keyword, but I couldn't find the syntax to my very simple problem below:

How do I redirect a file as command line arguments to the Linux command "touch"? I want to create a file with "touch abc.txt", but the filename should come from the filename "file.txt" which contains "abc.txt", not manually typed-in.

---

```
[root@machine ~]# touch < file.txt
touch: missing file operand
Try `touch --help' for more information.
[root@machine ~]# cat file.txt
abc.txt
```

Comment: You could consider `echo "abc.txt" | xargs touch`.

Comment: Please don't experiment on your machine as user `root`; you can do so much damage by accident!  Use `root` privileges when you must, and only when you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: What are the details of the real use case here? Details matter -- if you want to be able to pass all possible argument lists around, you'd need to work with NUL-delimited inputs. Also, if you need to handle arguments with whitespace, arguments with literal quotation marks, etc etc, those are things that not all proposed answers handle correctly either.

Comment: Nothing complicated: Simply to "touch" *one* file.

Comment: Ahh! With just one file, then it is indeed much easier. `touch "$(<file.txt)"` would even be enough there, if that file name can't end in a newline. (If you'd want a solution that worked for all possible filenames, which includes filenames ending in newlines, then it gets more complex again).

Comment: ...that said, the quotes *are* needed for that to work; if `file.txt` contains a name with spaces, and you used an answer without the quotes, it would create two separate files.

Comment: (BTW, your original title saying "arguments", plural, implied that you wanted to be able to read more than one argument from the same source file, leading in part to that misunderstanding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$ touch $(< file.txt)
```

to expand the content of `file.txt` and give it as argument to `touch`

Comment: That works in Bash.  You may need to replace the `<` with `cat` in (some) other shells.

Comment: Sorry, what I really need is that following. Some sort of piping, any help is appreciated.

[root@machine ~]# echo "abc.txt" | touch

touch: missing file operand
Try `touch --help' for more information.

Comment: `touch` does not take its argument through `stdin` . So you need then to use `xargs`: `echo 'abc.txt | xargs touch'

Comment: Boo, hiss -- can't have filenames with spaces inside a file expanded this way, globs will be expanded, and quotes will be treated in a very unfortunate way (an entry in the file `"hello world.txt"` will become a file named `"hello` -- starting with a literal quotation mark -- and another file named `world.txt"`).

Comment: ...whereas an entry `*** HELLO WORLD ***.doc` will have the first `***` replaced with a list of files in the current directory, and the `***.txt` replaced with a list of files ending in `.txt` in the current directory; again, very unlikely to be desired behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I should use single quote ', instead of double-quotes ", for my filename. Bad, bad me!!! Lesson learned.

Comment: @user1972031, actually, that issue exists with both quoting styles here. How best to avoid it depends on exactly how your file is formatted. The `xargs` approach will treat quotes as syntactic, thus not expecting them to be part of the literal filename, _unless_ you use `-0` or `-d`, in which case you don't need quotes for xargs input and shouldn't use them unless there are literal quotes in the filenames themselves.

Comment: BTW, the OP has clarified in a comment on the question that the intent is to touch only one file. To be correct in that use case, quotes are needed: `touch "$(<file.txt)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have multiple filenames stored in a file, you could use `xargs`, e.g.,

```
xargs touch <file.txt
```

(It would work for just one, but is more flexible than a simple "echo").

Comment: Might suggest `xargs -d$'\n' touch <file.txt`, if one has GNU xargs and wants to treat all characters other than newlines as literal. (Details depend on quoting format, etc).

Comment: yes... but perhaps a little sophisticated for OP's current question.  It is topical though, per `linux` tag.

Comment: Thing is that questions and their answers get reused by other people -- that's why we're building a knowledge base, after all. If they're sufficiently incomplete as to not cover correct usage, then someone who _needs_ correctness can end up going away without an adequate understanding of usage and limitations.

Comment: Perhaps.  However, to make a *suitable* answer incorporating your suggested change would be about a page of text.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Thanks for the alternative. Learn another tip today.